# add_action() is not working in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I create a function to receive the ajax calls in function.php (wordpress)

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_contact_us_receiver', 'contact_us_receiver_callback' );
function contact_us_receiver_callback() {
    echo "you are at right place ";
}
```

calling it in ajax url -:

```
              post_data = $("#contact_us_form").serialize();
                //Ajax post data to server
                $.post('contact_us_receiver', post_data, function(response){  

                    //load json data from server and output message     
                    if(response.type == 'error')
                    {
                     output = '<div class="alert alert-danger">'+response.text+'</div>';
                    }else{
                        output = '<div class=" alert alert-success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                        $('#contact_us_form input ').val('');
                         $('#contact_us_form select ').val('');
                      $('#contact_us_form textarea ').val('');
                    }

                    $('#result').html(output);
                    $('#contact_us_form input ').css('border','');
                    $('#contact_us_form select ').css('border','');
                }, 'json');
```

But it is giving me 404 not found error in console . please advise me how can i make call to my function .

Comment: add_action( 'wp_ajax_contact_us_receiver', 'contact_us_receiver_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_contact_us_receiver', 'contact_us_receiver_callback' );

Comment: not working still getting 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are sending your request to an url named `contact_us_receiver`, which probably does not exists and hence returns the 404.

In wordpress all ajax request run against the same URL. The specific action is then transmitted using the `action` parameter.

For more details and working examples have a look at the respective Codex article:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins